# How to aggregate text-data from a given date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database

I am creating an excel database to 1) track hours and 2) track event types. In Sheet1, I enter the individual events on a given date and the minutes spent. My goal is to get Sheet2 to consolidate.

**Sheet1**

| Date | Event Type | Time Spent (Minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-09 | Administration | 10 |
| 2021-12-09 | Council Meeting | 60 |
| 2021-12-05 | Community Service | 90 |
| 2021-12-05 | Administration | 10 |
| 2021-12-05 | Prep | 5 |

**Sheet2**

| Date | Events | Total Time (hh:mm) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-09 | Administration, Council Meeting | 01:10 |
| 2021-12-05 | Administration, Community Service, Prep | 01:45 |

I figured out how to Sheet2!C2:C3 using SUMIF, but how do I accomplish Sheet2!B?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365,you can combine `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTER` functions.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6=$A2))
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Office 365, you can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table24"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Event Type", type text}, 
        {"Time Spent (Minutes)", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by Date
// Aggregate by concatenating Event Type text and SUMming Minutes
//    (change minutes => duration to get desired output format
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {
        {"Event Type", each Text.Combine(List.Sort([Event Type]),", "), type nullable text}, 
        {"Time Spent (Minutes)", each #duration(0,0,List.Sum([#"Time Spent (Minutes)"]),0), type nullable duration}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]